# Passing arguments to execve(2) via registers

Tags: linux, gdb, disassembly, execve

I have wrote a short program to execute a bash using `execve(2)`.

my_prog.c

```
int main(){
    execve(Argument_1,Argument_2,NULL);
}
```

Here is the disassembly of `execve(2)` [neglecting the main assembly for simplicity]

```
(gdb) disassemble execve
Dump of assembler code for function execve:
   0xf7ea77e0 <+0>:     push   ebx
   0xf7ea77e1 <+1>:     mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x10]
   0xf7ea77e5 <+5>:     mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [esp+0xc]
   0xf7ea77e9 <+9>:     mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x8]
   0xf7ea77ed <+13>:    mov    eax,0xb
   0xf7ea77f2 <+18>:    call   DWORD PTR gs:0x10
   0xf7ea77f9 <+25>:    pop    ebx
   0xf7ea77fa <+26>:    cmp    eax,0xfffff001
   0xf7ea77ff <+31>:    jae    0xf7e0f730
   0xf7ea7805 <+37>:    ret
```

I found the arguments to `execv(2)` in the following registers

```
eax --> index of execve(2) in syscall table
ebx --> Argument_2
ecx --> Argument_3
```

and Argument_1 on the top of the stack

```
(gdb) x/xw $esp
0xffffce00:     0x080484ea
(gdb) x/s 0x080484ea
0x80484ea:      "/bin/bash"  <--- Argument_1
```

The edx contains `0x080484ab`

```
(gdb) x/xw 0x080484ab
0x80484ab <__libc_csu_init+75>: 0x8301c783
(gdb) x/xw 0x8301c783
0x8301c783:     Cannot access memory at address 0x8301c783
```

I am on linux-intel(x86) system, so i assume that all parameters to execve(2) should be passed via registers but i **couldn't found Argument_1 in any register** though it is present on the stack.

Comment: "I found the arguments" -- is meaningless without telling *where* in the code you are stopped.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that. I'm stopped at the first instruction of execve module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm stopped at the first instruction of execve module.

`execve` is not a "module", it's a `libc` function, which loads arguments into registers, and then performs the actual system call.

> i couldn't found Argument_1 in any register

If you stopped on instruction at address `0xf7ea77f2`, you *would*.

But you are stopped on entry into a C function `execve`, so the arguments are where a C function expects them. On `i*86`, the arguments are passed on the stack, so that's where you'll find them: `x/3wx $esp` is what you want (at that point in the program).